# Android WebView - Infinite loop after click

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to create simple child-safety browser on Android, and I want to check every url before load with this api: https://www.mywot.com/wiki/API. But sometimes after click on url starts infinite loop of load this link.
I try to override shouldOverrideUrlLoading like this:

```
private class BrowserWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

   private interface UrlCheckListener {
        void urlChecked(boolean isGood);
   }

   private void loadUrl(String query) {
            String safeUrl = UrlCheckerUtils.getSafeUrlFromQuery(query);
            checkUrlBeforeLoad(safeUrl, valid -> {
                if (isViewAttached()) {
                    if (valid) {
                        getView().loadPageByUrl(safeUrl);
                    } else {
                        getView().showError();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void checkUrlBeforeLoad(String url, UrlCheckListener listener) {
            try {
                URI uri = new URI(url);
                String domain = uri.getHost() + "/";

                wotService.getLinkReputation(domain)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(wotResponse -> listener.urlChecked(wotResponse.isSafe()));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                Timber.e(e, "Error while parsing url");
        }
    }
```

loadPageByUrl in view:

```
@Override
public void loadPageByUrl(String url) {
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Can you help me to fix this please?

Comment: in `loadPageByUrl`, you call `loadUrl`, which in turn call `loadPageByUrl`

Comment: @Danh and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android, I can't give you a correct answer. Try to use a debugger or find some tutorial out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in 
`String safeUrl = UrlCheckerUtils.getSafeUrlFromQuery(query);` where I created new object of String. When I start manipulate with `url` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, it starts work without infinite redirects.